# Apache web server: "proxying" a webapp from another server?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

Sorry for the lame terminology - I'm no way a sysadmin... So here's the deal. I have two Linux boxes in the same network, let's refer to those boxes by their IPs, a.b.c.d and e.f.g.h. Each box runs some webapp, normally available like `http://a.b.c.d/` and `http://e.f.g.h/`. What I want to accomplish is this: with some Apache web server (which by the way lives on both boxes) configuration voodoo, the first app would be available via `http://a.b.c.d/whatever1/`, and the 2nd app would be available as `http://a.b.c.d/whatever2/` - but would still reside on another server (e.f.g.h). Long story short - is it at all possible to do this with Apache configuration magic and without touching the webapps and their configuration? If so - how? :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a reverse proxy. Update httpd.conf with the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /whatever2/ http://e.f.g.h/
ProxyPassReverse /whatever2/ http://e.f.g.h/
```

http://a.b.c.d/whatever2/ should now give you what you want.

Comment: You could also take a look at nginx and use it instead of Apache as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpd.conf with a redirect

> Redirect /*web-page.html*
>   http://www.new-domain.com/*destination-web-page.html*

Or

.htaccess with redirects

HTH